# How to put error message when enter is pressed but no answer is given?

Tags: c++

My school task is to "Write a program that will accept month from January to December and will display its corresponding birthstone as you type your desired month. A message will appear once you misspelled the name of the month and another message box will appear if no month is typed on the textbox."

This is the code I made, but everytime I run it, all results end with 
'Enter a month (1-12): 3
Error! No month given.'
I know something's wrong about the order but I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help? Thanks!

P.S
The program should use switch statements

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

int main()
{
string in = "";
int n = 0;
while (true)
{
    cout << "Enter a month (1-12): ";
    getline(cin, in);
    std::stringstream (in);
    if (n)
        break;
    cout << "Error! No month given."<<std::endl;
}

int month;
    cout << "Enter a month (1-12): ";
    cin >>month;
switch (month) 
{
    case 1:
        cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Garnet";
        break;
    case 2:
        cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Amethyst";
        break;
    case 3:
        cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Aquamarine";
        break;
    case 4:
        cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Diamond";
        break;
    case 5:
        cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Emerald";
        break;
    case 6:
        cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Pearl";
        break;
    case 7:
        cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Ruby";
        break;
    case 8:
        cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Peridot";
        break;
    case 9:
        cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Sapphire";
        break;
    case 10:
        cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Opal";
        break;
    case 11:
        cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Topaz";
        break;
    case 12:
        cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Turquoise";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Error! Month is misspelled/does not exist.";
        break;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only condition in which the first loop will terminate is if `n` is non-zero.   `n` is zero before the loop, and is never changed.  The string that is read from `cin` is never checked.

Answer (score 0):

Where about's do you change `n` to equal **true** or `1`? As far as I can see you never change it so the error message will always be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your problem. may be help you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    string in = "";
    int n = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        int month;
        cout << "Enter a month (1-12): ";
        cin >>month;

        if(n)
        {
            cout << "Error! No month given."<<std::endl;
            break;
        }

        switch (month) 
        {
            case 1:
                cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Garnet";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Amethyst";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Aquamarine";
                break;
            case 4:
                cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Diamond";
                break;
            case 5:
                cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Emerald";
                break;
            case 6:
                cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Pearl";
                break;
            case 7:
                cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Ruby";
                break;
            case 8:
                cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Peridot";
                break;
            case 9:
                cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Sapphire";
                break;
            case 10:
                cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Opal";
                break;
            case 11:
                cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Topaz";
                break;
            case 12:
                cout <<"Corresponding Birthstone= Turquoise";
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Error! Month is misspelled/does not exist.";
                n = 1;
                break;
        }
        cout<<std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped a lot, although when I press enter, the error message doesn't come up. I think something is still wrong, but thank you so much for helping!